# Iphone working with icons

Tags: iphone, icons

I want to write a simple program which can customize iphone icons like their positions or something like theme creators. and I want to know how some programs' settings are in the iphone main setting tab. I really need help.
thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to retheme the springboard (the place where apps icons are displayed) you can't. If you want to retheme things inside your own application it is doable, but it really depends on the design of your application.

To get your apps settings into the Settings app you just need to add a Settings.bundle to your app, which a plist describing the preferences. There is documentation for it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's an app that already does this for jailbroken iPhones. It's called iconoclasm, you can get it from Cydia.